# What is type route when I use it like param?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I use route like:

```
<Stack.Screen
 component={VacancyChat}
 name='VacancyChat'
 options={({ route }: any) => ({
   title: route?.params?.order.title,
 })}
/>
```

What type of route I should use here instead of any?

Answer (score 0):

Here is type of Stack.Screen `option`:

```js
    options?: ScreenOptions | ((props: {
        route: RouteProp<ParamList, RouteName>;
        navigation: any;
    }) => ScreenOptions);
```